# Java library for showing network graphically

Tags: java, networking, social-networking

I want to depict a network graphically (one IP connecting to different IPs) , where i can show one node connecting to two or more nodes.Something like this.Suggest me some library in JAVA which can help me in doing this.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe jgraph could be used?

http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html

Or NetBeans Visual Library?

http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/

Comment: +1 for the NetBeans Visual Library. I was going to suggest the same

Comment: Ironically I've been using jgraph to display some organisation hierarchies within a program based on the NetBeans platform... I should port that to NB Visual Library, but need to find the time for it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net) library .

> is a library that provides a common and extendible language for the
>   modeling, analysis, and visualization of data that can be represented
>   as a graph or network.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a library that combines [JUNG and NetBeans Visual Library](https://timboudreau.com/blog/NetBeans_Visual_Library_Meets_JUNG/read) so you can use JUNG's layouts against real components.